# FindElement is not an attribute of webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm getting this error every time I use `FindElement(By.xpath("//...` syntax instead of `find_element_by_xpath(...` etc, telling me that `FindElement is not an attribute of webdriver`. What form of declaration I have to write down to make it an attribute. I only use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://demoqa.com/text-box')

EnterFullName = driver.FindElement(By.xpath('//input[contains(@id,"userName")'])
EnterFullName.send_keys("Daniel Soth")
```

It is obviously working if I write down this line of code:

```
EnterFullName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userName"]')

EnterFullName.send_keys("Daniel Soth")
```

However I'm intrigued by this FindElement attribute that is simply not working and I would like someone to explain why and what I need to declare in order to make it work.

Comment: please post the code where you've used `FindElement` at

Comment: `find_element` is a method over the driver instance. I.e: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ... )`

Comment: I really want to use FindElement attribute. I can do it differently but I would like to know how to use the FindElement. thanks

Comment: I believe it should be something with import org.openqa. selenium.Webdriver and WebElement. There is no such thing as orq.openqa to install. Really foggy right now.

Comment: To understand that FindElement is a Java attribute that can be used with Selenium package but not with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindElement` has been named as `driver.find_element` in the python package (in accordance with python's [naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)).

This is how you use it in python:

```
enter_full_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'userName')]")
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out and I simply can't. The expression '//input[contains(@id,"userName")') is invalid. Error: the expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Since you told us you were facing `FindElement is not an attribute of webdriver` error, I only focused on solving that and took the expression as granted :) give me a moment to check that

Comment: That's correct. I started with the findElement because most of the examples posted use that and I thought it can be used in Python but in reality it is used only in Java with org.opanqa.selenium.webdriver and WebElement declaration in the beginning in order to be recognized as an attribute. I'm still confused what is org.openqa and how could be installed for use with Selenium in Python.

Comment: I believe that's just selenium's java package name. (it's common to use company domain reversed in Java). Don't worry about it if you're only using python

Comment: please try the code from the updated answer as is. (without changing quotemarks)

Comment: Yes I tried it from the updated answer and only added an "s" to element. same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223559/discussion-between-tibebes-m-and-daniel).

Comment: @Daniel please consider upvoting/accepting this answer should you find it useful. It would help a lot